# Creating filters of different content types which goes as contextual filters to the view on submit. I created a form inside a block

Tags: php, forms, drupal-7, view

```
  form['year']=>
  array(
   '#title' => t('Year'),
  '#type' => 'select',
   '#options' => _load_year(),
   '#ajax' => array(
    'event'=>'change',
    'callback' =>'call_back_function,
    'wrapper' => 'image_place',

    ),
  );

  $form['firstimage_wrapper']['image1'] = array(
   '#name' => 'image1',   
   '#type' => 'image_button',
   '#src' =>$base_url .'/xxx/css/images/image_1.png',
   '#attributes' => array(
   'class' => array('opaque'), ),
   '#ajax' => array(
     'event'=>'click',
     'callback' =>'call_back_function2',
     'wrapper' => 'list-wrapper',

      ),
      );

    $form['secondimage_wrapper']['image2'] = array(
    '#name' => 'image2',   
   '#type' => 'image_button',
  '#src' =>$base_url .'/xxx/css/images/BDS_2.png',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('opaque'),),
 '#ajax' => array(
    'event'=>'click',
     'callback' =>'call_back_function2',
    'wrapper' => 'list-wrapper',

    ),
    );

   $form['group']=>
     array(
    '#title' => t('Group'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => _load_group(),
   '#ajax' => array(
      'event'=>'change',
     'callback' =>'call_back_function3,
      'wrapper' => 'group_place',

        ),
        );

     $form["submit"] = array(
    "#value"  => t("Go"),   
    "#type"   => "submit",
    "#submit" => array("some_function"),
      );

     function _load_year()
      {
                // loading the year from the taxonomy terms
      }

     function call_back_function($form, &$form_state)
      {
           // writing the code for enabling and making the buttons visible depending on the year
          // selection from the list.
       } 

      function call_back_function2($form, &$form_state)
       {
           // checking the name of the triggerring element 
               $name = $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'];
        }

          function _load_group()
          {
           // loading the group from the database depending on the image selected
          }
```

I am not able to access the $name which is inside the call_back_function2 to the _load_group(). I  tried $_SESSION, variable_set()... but these are not working properly everytime i need to reload.
Please help me i am stuck and could not go further.

Comment: If it's in the SESSION, did you add `session_start()` at the top of the page?

Comment: i have done that but missed adding, my problem is to store the value and use it in another function, session is not working properly